# Directory names causing errors when setting bucket contents to public?

Tags: s3cmd

I am using `s3cmd` (version 2.0.1) to set all the contents of a bucket/directory as public, but I can't set the object's acl as public for directories named with all lower case characters. I can only set the bucket contents as public if the bucket name is all upper case, or a mix of lower and upper case.

For example, this doesn't work:

I created a new bucket with rclone:
`rclone mkdir remotename:name`
And then tried to set the contents to public: `s3cmd setacl s3://name --acl-public`
and get the error `ERROR: S3 error: 405 (MethodNotAllowed)`

But this does work:

Create a new bucket: `rclone mkdir remotename:NEWNAME`
and successfully set the contents of that as public with: `s3cmd setacl s3://NEWNAME --acl-public`

Is there a limitation to what I can call my buckets/directories, or is there something I'm not understanding about setting bucket contents to public with s3cmd?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, got it fixed. The issue has to do with s3cmd. In my `.s3cfg` file on the `host_bucket` line, I removed the “s” after `$(bucket)`. Once I did this I could create and make public whatever bucket name I want.